# Is Read Committed Snapshot with EF Savechanges causing race condition

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework-6, ef-code-first, code-first

I'm having an issue with EF6 using a Code-First approach where a new DB Context attempting to access an entity is causing a null reference exception. Here is an example of my scenario:

**Main thread**

```
int personId = 0;
using(var ctx = new exampleContext())
{
  var person = new Person() {Name = "Alex"};
  ctx.People.Add(person);
  ctx.SaveChanges();
  personId = person.id;
}

Task.Run(() => {someOtherThread(personId)})
```

**Some Other Thread**

```
public static someOtherThread(int personId)
{
     using(var ctx = new exampleContext())
     {
        var person = ctx.People.Where(x => x.id == personId);
        //Exception here.
        var name = person.Name;
     }
}
```

When I turn the Is Read Committed Snapshot option off in the DB, this works as expected (on by default when EF creates DB), but we want to maintain the most optimistic concurrency control model possible.

I think what's happening is that SaveChanges is not waiting for the new snapshot to be created on the database and as a result the other thread is reading the old snapshot.

Note that if I sleep the thread until it can get the record it will eventually so the SaveChanges is not silently failing.

Is there anything I am missing here? Is this a possible bug with EF or does this work as expected? If it is working as expected, what is the best practice to get around this?

Thanks!

Comment: Maybe it has to do with connection pooling. I once had an issue with strange locking behavior in SQL Server 2019 where it turned out that the pool returned a connection which had serialized transaction isolation set from a former query and the isolation level was not properly reset when the connection was handed to a new session. In your case maybe the connection returned from the pool is still associated with an older snapshot. That's only an assumption.

Answer (score 0):

its returning null because .Add is not writing changes to db so you have to `SaveChanges()` first then you will be able to reach the new Person's id by the way you try to.

```
 var person = new Person() {Name = "Alex"};
      ctx.People.Add(person);
      personId = person.id;
```

in code should be

```
var person = new Person() {Name="Alex"};
ctx.People.Add(person);
ctx.SaveChanges();
personId=person.id;
```

also if you put a breakpoint on personId you will see the value returning 0 until you call `SaveChanges()`

Comment: Hello Halil. Thanks for the comment! My apologies in not writing this example more carefully. I Save changes before I return the id. The id gets sent successfully to the other thread. The exception occurs in the other thread when querying with the "correct" id. I will fix my example

Comment: oh so same thing gonna happen you gotta call `personId=person.id` right after `SaveChanges()` so it will gonna be working i have faced same issue today

Comment: hmm if you your code is already running as you are corrected it should be working can you put breakpoints and tell me what exception you are getting ?

Comment: Sure. This gets the person.id correctly in the Main thread. It even gets it correctly if I spin up a new dbContext in the same thread again. The issue occurs when I try to query with the "committed" id in the other thread.

Comment: `var person = ctx.People.Where(x => x.id == personId);` can you try this one as `var person = ctx.People.Where(x => x.id == personId).Single();` ?

Comment: I use FirstOrDefault in the actual code and run into the same issue. Thanks for the tip though!

Comment: hmm that's the all tricks i have since i don't have chance to take a look at code.